# Where should the `build` phase happen in setuptools?

Tags: python, node.js, django, setuptools

This a question about *setuptools* and creating a python distribution for a web application.

**Context**

It is a django project and we distribute it via a private pypi, to ourselves, not external users (yet).  Currently we run `python setup.py sdist` to create the distribution and we upload that to our pypi. I suspect it is just a copy of the source code as a tar.gz.  We checkout the source to do development. We don't install for dev via pip (perhaps we should?).

Recently the project has started using `nodejs`.  Which now means that now we need to do a "build" to create new files which are not part of the source code, but do need to be deployed.  The build process requires a bunch of node packages which are not a necessary, or desired, part of the final deployment to a webserver.

Reading through [the packaging documentation](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/) it describes `sdist`, `bdist_wheel`, and also `develop` targets for `setup.py`, but I'm not clear on how to apply these to our situation.

### Question 1

When we pull from our pypi, what should we be pulling?

- the pre-built deployable version of code for the webserver, without source code?, or
- code on which we run something else which builds and arranges things as they need to be?  If so, what would the appropriate setup.py target be (sdist, bdist_wheel, a new custom target)?

### Question 1 (put another way)

When, and how, should we run the build?

To 'build' the app, we run nodejs-javascript scripts eg: `npm install`, and `less x y x`, or `webpack -p`, or python, scripts which convert the source files into deployable files.  We don't want these things on the web server.

**Discussion**

So, generally speaking, as you can tell, first we're a bit confused about **when** to convert the source files into distribution files.  And second, **how** to actually implement that: *subprocess* calls to shell scripts from a subclassed `setuptools.command`?!?

We'd prefer not to push the finished product to pypi because then all the bits and bobs we do to create the build are not captured and automated in a neat `setuptools` centric way.  So when, where, and how do we incorporate the build process into our setuptools distribution?

<sup>* Note: adding more confusion about what/where we're also using [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)</sup>

Comment: Have you made any progress on this or do you have found any resources?

Comment: @madflow It was complicated.  We deployed a docker with all the compiled and ready-to-roll stuff in it.  That was built by another docker, the builder, which installed all the build tools and packages to itself, plus the python package.  Then did the build which generated the deployable docker.  Thus distro packages were installed via the dockerfile(s) and some building was written into the setup.py.   I recall thinking afterward that the python in setup wasn't strictly necessary and could actually be a regular script on the build machine. It sounds messy and it was. Hopefully you'll do better

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Build pipelines are the "beast". I think my use case is much simpler - more the "how" part + a webpack build. I am adapting this: https://github.com/djblets/djblets/blob/master/setup.py at the moment.